# Yesod + System.Process

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to create an application using Yesod and I need to call a function that uses `System.Process`.

But I'm receiving this error:

> Could not find module `System.Process`

`System.Process` is needed because I want to use `callCommand`.

Comment: By the way, I'm importing System.Process using 'import System.Process'

Comment: Add the `process` under `dependencies` section in either the cabal file or the `package.yaml` file if you are using recent yesod scaffolding site.

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks a lot, Sibi!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the  package `process` under dependencies section in either the cabal file or the `package.yaml` file if you are using recent yesod scaffolding site.